# Why there is 'were' not 'was in this sentence?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, auxiliary-verbs

from
[the BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/towards-advanced/unit-17/session-1)

> Advanced learners often automatically invert the subject and auxiliary verb after a WH word clause, as if it **were** a question.

'It' is a third person singular pronoun, why does 'were' follows 'it'? Also, 'it' refers to **a** 'WH word clause' which is singular, isn't it?

I checked with Grammarly Premium and it says it's OK with 'were'.

Answer (score 4):

"Were" in the last clause is in the subjunctive mood. The clause, starting with "as if it..." is stating something that is untrue or hypothetical.